# Issue with setting form response destination (possibly an issue with getID() function)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

---

### **NOTE:** This issue has been brought to the attention of google dev's and they are apparently looking into solving this. There is no solution yet, [please see here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Type%3DDefect%20Failed%20to%20set%20response%20destination.&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=3700) if this issue affects you too!

---

I have been working with a small project for a while in google script, I ran my script and received the "Failed to set response destination. Verify the destination ID and try again." error. This occured in a section of my code where various forms are generated each with a corresponding response spreadsheet, the error triggers on the first .setDestination() call:

```
responseSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.create('ConflictRespData for ' + activeRef.refereePi);
moveToFolder(DocsList.getFileById(responseSheet.getId()), conflictFolder);
Logger.log(responseSheet.getId());

conflForm = FormApp.create('Conflict Declerations for ' + activeRef.refereePi);
moveToFolder(DocsList.getFileById(conflForm.getId()), conflictFolder);
conflForm.setDescription(FORM_DESCRIPTION)
         .setConfirmationMessage(CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE)
         .setAllowResponseEdits(false)
         .setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false)
conflForm.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, responseSheet.getId());
```

my code was working fine the last time I used it 2 days ago and running it today with no editing of anything I am now receiving this error. This leads me to believe this is an error on google's side, not in my own syntax.

I used the Logger to print the .getId() of the responseSheet after it was created and noticed that this string does not match the one seen in the address bar when I navigate to the spreadsheet through my google Drive, however pasting this Id in place of the actual id takes me to the spreadsheet.. I was under the impression that Id's must be unique.

I created a new script which is (essentially) an exact copy of the sample script on the [Class Form page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) in the GAS documentation to support my suspicion that this is a google-side issue:

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1ib3j66ogj3NgozVDeYxhNdqm6PaajUhN3dk24BXcd7s');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Spreadsheet Name');

  // Update form properties via chaining.
  form.setTitle('Form Name')
     .setDescription('Description of form')
     .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
     .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
     .setAcceptingResponses(false);

 // Update the form's response destination.
 form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
}
```

And yes in fact I still receive the same error message, and as well the Id of the spreadsheet when printed to the log does not match the Id in the browser navigation bar.

I would appreciate some insight as to the nature of this issue, or if there is something I am doing wrong here (although the exact same code was working before so I'm inclined to think not). If you can offer any help that would be great, I can't progress further without dealing with this issue.

Comment: Some problem here! Until this morning, my scripts worked just fine and today I get also the error message. There is already an open issue at the Google Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Type%3DDefect%20Failed%20to%20set%20response%20destination.&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=3700

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now fixed. I'm adding this here just to close the question.

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Type%3DDefect%20Failed%20to%20set%20response%20destination.&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=3700