# Setting Google Form response destination not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-form-quiz

I've been using a script to generate Google Form Quizzes automatically from source data contained in a Google spreadsheet.It was working fine till yesterday, but today i see an error "Failed to set response destination. Verify the destination id and try again." I could successfully replicate this issue in five other independent deployments of the script. The error is at the line "setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId()). This is a little strange, given that this issue cropped up without any changes made to the script and the script was running fine for more than a year.

Comment: I have also checked for any possible discontinuation of methods, but none of the methods i had used seem to have been deprecated.

Comment: Looks like a bug that existed earlier and subsequently got resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997412/issue-with-setting-form-response-destination-possibly-an-issue-with-getid-fun. But seems to have resurfaced. Hopefully it will get resolved.